# How to read XML Values in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to read data from the table which has XML values but the data type is text and not XML. I want to read the name and value for each ID.

For example: Table name is Data

```
 ID               Catalogs                                 
--------|--------------------------------------------------------
1       | <item><item name="XXX" Value="1234" />  
        | <item><item name="yy" Value="123" /><item>
2       | <item> <item name="XX" Value="134" /><item>
```

Comment: Where is your unsuccessful attempt?

Comment: Change the column to XML and use `nodes()` and `value()` to extract the data. Try it out and return when you run into some problem with that.

Comment: I don't how to read it.

Comment: [nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Within a query, use `CAST` or `CONVERT` to change the data to the XML datatype, and go from there, e.g.

```
SELECT cast(Catalogs as XML) CatalogXML
 from Data
```

The XML has to be well-formed or you'll get an error. Depending on complexity, you might have to make this a subquery.